# How many isomorphisms are there of a given graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am bit confused about some conventions about how this counting is done in different literatures. Say one is given a graph on $n$ vertices labelled, $a_1,a_2,...a_n$. Now isn't any of the permutations of the labels of the graph a distinct isomorphic copy of the graph? And hence there are $n!$ isomorphic copies of a graph.  Right?

---

I am using the definition that graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic iff there is a bijective function $f : V(G_1) \rightarrow V(G_2)$ such that $(x,y) \in E(G_1)$ iff $(f(x),f(y)) \in E(G_2)$

---

Hence any permutation of the labels of the graph naturally gives such a $f$ and hence the relabelled graph is isomorphic to the original one. Right?

Answer (score 2):

What you claim is that an automorphism of a graph is simply a bijection of its set of vertices to itself. But note that there is an extra condition (which makes an isomorphism more than a bijection), namely that the bijection should also preserve the edges (in general this is preserving the structure of the space).

Your claim is true for complete graphs though (why?).

To further illustrate this, take the following example: Take the simple graph $G$ with three vertices and two edges: $a-b-c$.

---

**Edit:** Let us see why $|Aut(G)|=2$. Let $f\in Aut(G)$. Suppose $f(b)\neq b$. Wlog, set $f(b):=c$. $ab$ and $bc$ are the edges of $G$. As $f$ is an automorphism, we must have $f(a)f(b)$ and $f(b)f(c)$ to be the edges of $G$ as well. But this cannot happen since $f(b)=c$ has exactly one edge attached to it. Thus $b$ is a fixed point of $f$. Further, there are two automorphisms of the graph, namely the identity and the one that changes the places of $a$ and $c$. Hence the result follows.

Comment: For any permutation of the vertex labels isn't there automatically a $f$ as in the definition which preserves the edge structure? The permutation itself gives such a $f$. If a vertex with label "a" gets now a label "b" then declare $f(a) = b$. Doing this for every vertex gives us a valid $f$ which preserves the connectivity structure. [...I don't see what has complete graphs got to do with it...]

Comment: [ if you consider the graph on 3 vertices and with 2 edges as $a-b-c$ then it clearly has $5$ more isomorphic representations of it as $a-c-b$, $b-a-c$, $b-c-a$, $c-a-b$, $c-b-a$...all these 6=3! graphs are isomorphic...]

Comment: No, try again. (Hint: if $f$ is an automorphism of the example I have given then the number of edges with $b$ and $f(b)$ as an endpoint must be the same.)

Comment: Start with the graph $a-b-c$ and look at the graph $b-a-c$. Now isn't this an $f$ which will work i.e $f(a) =b,f(b)=a,f(c)=c$. What property does this $f$ violate to not be an automorphism?

Comment: I'll add the explanation to my answer.

Comment: I think we are talking of two different things here and I also misused some terminology.  (a) I obviously agree with you that there are $2$ automorphisms of the graph $a-b-c$. (b) But I am also right when I say that the graph $a-b-c$ is isomorphic to the graph $b-a-c$. I believe that these two are different concepts!

Comment: I don't know what is the correct terminology to express this fact that these $n!$ permutations of the labels of the vertices of a graph are also isomorphic to the original graph. (but not all of them are related by an automorphism of the original graph)

Comment: If you are using the same letters to denote what $f$ does to each point (so that it maps the vertex named $b$ to the vertex named $a$ in your example), then the $f$ you describe is not an isomorphism. Or else, you use the same three letters with no connection with their original usages whatsoever, in which case there are no concrete upper bounds for the number of isomorphisms (use $d,e,f$ and then $g,h,i$ to get $12$ more and so on). The point is that if you could simply count the number of orderings the vertices then you are not making use of the restriction imposed by the edges.

Comment: I am saying keep the same vertex set $V=(a,b,c)$ (and keep it fixed once and for all) Now consider the two graphs $G1=(a-b-c)$ and $G2=(b-a-c)$. Isn't $G1$ isomorphic to $G2$?  (thats what I am trying to say)

Comment: Ok so you simply use the same labels to name the vertices and say that $f=\{(a,b),(b,a),(c,c)\}$ is an isomorphism between these two graphs. This is true, but it amounts to only saying that if we have an unlabelled graph with $n$ vertices, then there are $n!$ ways to label its vertices, which is not so different than saying that there are $n!$ many bijections from a set with $n$ elements to itself.

Comment: Yes. But from the point of view of say the "Graph Isomorphism" decision question giving $G1$ and $G2$ as an input to the decider is still a non-trivial input! This permutation is still known to be impossible to detect without an exhaustive search. (and $n!$ is exponentially growing thing!) So this is in no way trivial as far as I can see!

Comment: I am having difficulty in understanding the issue, maybe you shoud provide a concrete example for which you can't decide whether the graphs are isomorphic or not.

Comment: Just consider any huge graph and another copy of it with its labels randomly permuted somehow. There is no easy way to detect that these two are isomorphic graphs except by an exhaustive search through the $n!$ possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

If we permute the vertices in all $n!$ ways, we will generate $n!$ *not necessarily distinct* graphs.  Recall that two graphs are *equal* if the have the same vertex set and edge set.

E.g. the permutation that swaps vertices $1$ and $3$ in the example below will return a graph equal to the graph we started off with.

[image]

Given a graph $G$, the permutations that return $G$ are called *automorphisms* of $G$, and together they form the automorphism group $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$.  We will generate $$\frac{n!}{|\mathrm{Aut}(G)|}$$ distinct graphs isomorphic to $G$, each generated $|\mathrm{Aut}(G)|$ times.

---

However, your definition of isomorphism has "$V(G_1)$" and "$V(G_2)$", suggesting that the vertex sets might be different.  In this case, there are an infinite number of isomorphic graphs (provided the graph has a vertex).  E.g.

[image]

are three isomorphic graphs on different vertex sets, and if we keep adding $1$ to the bottom vertex label, we will generate infinitely many unequal but isomorphic graphs.